# How to show characters when using the change "c" command

Tags: vim, vimrc

I know there is a vim setting that allows you to show characters when using the change command, I just can't find what it is.

Ex:

```
"This is a<ci"> string"
```

Inside the `<>` is where I use the `ci"` command to change the quotes. The setting I am talking about would change the string to something like:

```
"<>This is a strin$"
```

Comment: You can get vim to behave this way using ``:set compatible``, but this puts it into a mode that is closer to "pure" vi, so you probably lose out on other vim enhancements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to find

```
:set cpo+=$
```